CSS Infinite Marquee Issue on iOS Safari and Chrome
I’ve created an infinite marquee, but I’m encountering an issue on iOS devices when using Chrome or Safari. After the animation completes, the next frame briefly shows the text at the starting position before restarting the animation. However, this issue does not occur on Android devices or on Chrome’s mobile device emulator in the developer tools on a computer.
How can I modify my code to make it work correctly on iOS devices?
marquee issue
Here is the code I’m using for my infinite marquee


.marquee {
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.marquee-item {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    animation: marquee-animation 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes marquee-animation {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        left: 0%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
<div class="marquee">
     <span class="marquee-item">
         Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
     </span>
</div>




Text-wrap: no wrap isn’t implemented on older versions of IOS. What version are you on?

Are you allowed to alter the HTML?

My iOS version is 18.1.1. HTML modifications are possible.

I am not able to see the marquee issue example you give.

You can run my code snippet on an iOS device, and you'll see the flickering issue. I'm using an iPhone 13, and I can observe this problem. I also tested it on my friend's iPhone 15 Pro, and the same issue occurs. However, my friends using Android devices don't experience this problem; everything displays correctly on their phones.

Sorry, misunderstanding. I am trying to look at the png you have linked to, and I'm getting 'Forbidden'.

This isn't a totally general answer because it deals with the case where the text fits within the min-width given to the parent - i.e. it seems OK for the code as given in the question but may not satisfy your real-use case.
It scraps positioning in the animation via the left property because that appears to be what causes IOS to have a frame painted (even with opacity 0 which I tested) so causing the flickery effect.
Instead it uses transforms only - moving the item the sum of its width and the width of the parent.


<style>
  .marquee {
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    --mW: 500px;
    max-width: var(--mW);
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .marquee-item {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    animation: marquee-animation 5s infinite linear forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes marquee-animation {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc((-1 * var(--mW)) - 100%));
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="marquee">
  <span class="marquee-item">
         Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
     </span>
</div>



Note: I removed the -webkit settings because your code will only work on fairly uptodate versions of IOS anyway - text-wrap was not implemented until version 17.4 (in Safari MacOS as well as IOS).

This is because you are animating left. Apply animation to transform with will-change: transform;, or transform: translate3d(); - it will be smooth.
Another question is how to make the animated text appear immediately after disappearing.


.marquee {
  height: 26px;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.marquee-item {
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation: marquee-animation 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes marquee-animation {
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
<div class="marquee">
  <span class="marquee-item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </span>
</div>




Thank you for providing the translate3d method, but it is really a headache if the animated text cannot appear immediately after disappearing. And I added the left and transform attributes of will-change and it has no effect.
Later I tried to use requestAnimationFrame and felt it had the best effect.
I also tried animationend event to restart the animation but it felt like there would be a bit of a delay.
I don’t know if this problem can be solved using only css haha
